# AJAX response not working with PHP require_once

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have issue with ajax response. 
My test php file content looks like:

```
<?php
  $values = array('value'=>'123',           
    'key'=>'Test'
  );
  echo json_encode($values);
?>
```

And everything works perfectly. But problem is when I try but include database connection file then response stops.

Basically if I add `require_once 'database.php';` Connection file content:

```
<?php
  $login = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=SERVER;Database=db", "login", "pass");
?>
```

I already tried with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but nothing. This connection is fine, file location is fine as well. And working with another website.

test.php file content:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

 require_once 'database.php';

$values = array('value'=>'123',                 
       'key'=>'test');
echo json_encode($values);
?>
```

file database.php in right location.

Comment: is it showing any error??

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see what the actual error is?

Comment: When you navigate to the PHP page directly in your browser, what happens? Any Console errors?

Comment: in which file are you using the `require_once()`?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju no no errors at all

Comment: @SajibAcharya I'm using in test.php file where array is

Comment: @Twisty php error log file didn't show anything

Comment: can you post your complete `test.php` code while using `require_once(...)`?

Comment: @SajibAcharya please see updated question

Comment: Is your `database.php` `echoing` anything, or sending any results? I once faced this exact similar problem since I was using two seperate `<?php ... ?>` tags. That is why I wanted to be sure if this is the problem you are facing as well or not.

Comment: @SajibAcharya is not echoing because that's only contain db connection script. But if I run sql query with that connection everything fine in test.php file except ahax response.

Comment: Could you please copy the contents of `database.php` within `test.php` and then see if the ajax is working or not? And keep everything within one `<?php ... ?>` tag. Also, you are saying the ajax is not working. Where are you trying to get the ajax? Are you sure there is no problem in that code block where you want your ajax contents?

Comment: @SajibAcharya databse file content is above. Everything in one <?php ... ?> tag. ajax request is fine because working without response_once 'database.php';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96125/discussion-between-sajib-acharya-and-klapsius).

Comment: In your test php you need to echoing something, if you call a script only with a database connection it no return anything. What do you spect on the return? can you post the ajax call?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Your server might not support PDO.

Comment: have you found solution for this issue.. i have same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go step by step:-

1.) First of all you need to run your test.php file directly to ensure that there are no errors or warnings.

2.) If the file runs and echos the json data perfectly(without any warnings or errors), only then run the ajax call to get the response.

3.) You will certainly get the response.if not,then the problem might in your ajax function.